# Why are the contents of my Downloads folder duplicating to my account folder?

Tags: windows, duplicate, deduplication

I just went to my C:/Users/[username] folder and noticed that every file that is in my downloads folder is also in my [username] folder. Why is that happening and how can I get this to stop?

Comment: Have you tried downloading something with a different browser and seeing if this still happens?

Comment: Also, is one folder Quick Access?  Pointer to the real folder?  Check the full true name in the Windows Explorer bar